# Select all elements in a list after class is matched

Tags: html, css

**Code:**

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li class="animate-out">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a CSS selector that will select all of the items of the list after the one with the `animate-out` class?

I can target the one with animate out for the animation, but I want to simultaneously slide the remaining items up.

One caveat, it is possible that more then one item might be being removed simultaneously.

Is this possible to do with straight CSS or do I need to use JS to do this animation properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use sibling selector `~` like this:

```css
.animate-out ~ li {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li class="animate-out">Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```